# Subversion 1.8.x giving 400 Bad Request errors

Tags: svn, ssl, https

I've recently upgraded my svn client to the 1.8 branch (1.8.3) and now I can no longer update or commit anything to our server (through HTTPS).

It keeps giving the following error:

> C:\lavori\XPadStore>svn update Updating '.': svn: E175002: Unable to
>   connect to a repository at URL
>   'https://tanis@xxx.yyy.it/svn/eMagazine-Reader/trunk/XPadStore' svn:
>   E175002: Unexpected HTTP status 400 'Bad Request' on
>   '/svn/eMagazine-Reader /trunk/XPadStore'
>
> C:\lavori\XPadStore>

Comment: Is there any proxy server (e.g. IIS reverse-proxy) between your machine and the server? Anything logged to it's log (svn server/ proxy server)?

Comment: @bahrep no, there's no proxy in-between. And I can't find anything interesting in the logs. Reverting back to 1.7 everything works fine again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- In case you use Integrated Windows Authentication, read the article [KB98: 'HTTP status 400 Bad Request' error when a user connects to VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00098/).
- In case you access the server by FQDN or hostname that contains `_` underscore character -- remove or replace the underscore. Underscore characters are considered to be *invalid* in hostnames and due to security fixes in Apache HTTP Server 2.2.32 (released on 2017-01-13), SVN servers linked with this version reject client access by such invalid hostname or FQDN. The security fixes addressed the following vulnerabilities: CVE-2016-8743 and CVE-2016-5387.

---

Outdated answer that might still be helpful for someone using outdated SVN 1.8.x clients:

1. Use Subversion 1.8.8 (or newer) client.
2. When Subversion 1.8 is installed on the client, open the file in text editor "%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers" and add the following string to `[Global]` section: `http-chunked-requests = no`.
   See if it helps.
3. Your antivirus can break Subversion 1.8 traffic while working with Subversion 1.7 and older clients, so it makes sense to remove the antivirus and check whether it helps:

   So if have antivirus application installed on you machine -- disable it temporarily and see whether it helps. If it does not help -- remove the antivirus and again try to reproduce the issue. I guess that you won't get the error anymore with svn 1.8 client.

Comment: I confirm `http-chunked-requests=no` fixed my trouble when passing through an authenticated proxy

Comment: @YvesMartin what Subversion client do you use? What is its version? Make sure that you use up-to-date Subversion server and client!

Comment: The issue appears with TortoiseSVN 1.8.12 version connecting to Apache 2.4 with Subversion 1.6 WebDAV module.

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285  and this does not work

Comment: @morty346 do you use Integrated Windows Authentication (i.e. Kerberos) to authenticate to the server? In such case, read the article https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00098/

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - htp-chunked-request=no works for me! Using Kaspersky as antivir.

Comment: Great solution for me. Thanks